# While I want to Display Error message, other component pops up error in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, axios, use-state

I make something like that, When I fetch data, I pull stackoverflow users, when the stackoverflow user doesn't exist, I want to display Error Page by using `useState()`

In my Fetching API, function I have written that

```js
const [isError, setIsError] = useState<boolean>(false)
const [data, setData] = useState<any>([])

const fetchUser = async () => {
  await axios.get("URL")
  .then(userData => {
    if (userStats.data.items.length === 0) {
          setIsError(true)
          console.log("User Doesn't Exist")
       }
    else {setData(userStats.data.items[0])}
    //Up there I decalre my useState with that fetched API
  })
}
```

When I input in input field some random letter which user really doesn't exist I check my `useState` boolean
*If it is true I want to return my `ErrorPage` component if it's false `Success` Prop Componenet*

```js
if(isError){
  return <ErrorPage />
}

return <Success username={data.userName}/>
```

I get in console log -> `"User Doesn't Exist"` and also React error

> **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userName')**

I know `userName` doesn't exist in data but when `isError` is true why my if statement doesn't ignore last return?

***code up there what is shown is the logic what I do***

if something else missing comment me down and I will edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried in my if statement

```js
if (userStats.data.items.length === 0)
```

and it doesn't pop up error anymore

Answer (score 1):

Your component didnt know that isError changed. It is executing as if it is still false.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if(isError){
       return <ErrorPage />
    }
  },[isError]);
```

And of course you must import useEffect from react like this.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

Comment: I tried that but, I get Error not in console, React shows Error on Page `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userName')`

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think the problem here is that you are calling an "async" function that will not provide the result "Istantly", so when your code comes to :

```js
if(isError){
  return <ErrorPage />
}
return <Success username={data.userName}/>
```

Your variable *isError* hasn't been set yet.

So basically it's loading with *isError* as default value (false) (if you want just try to initalize it to *true*).

There are multiple ways to fix that. For example you can load a

```
<Loading>
```

Component while the async function is going on. So basically in your code :

```js
const [isError, setIsError] = useState<boolean>(false)
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
const [data, setData] = useState<any>([])

const fetchUser = async () => {
  await axios.get("URL")
  .then(userData => {
    if (userStats.data.items.length === 0) {
          setIsError(true)
          setIsLoading(false)
          console.log("User Doesn't Exist")
       }
    else 
    {
          setData(userStats.data.items[0])
          setIsLoading(false)
     }
    //Up there I decalre my useState with that fetched API
  })
}
```

and

```js
if(isLoading)
{
   return <Loading/>
}
if(isError){
  return <ErrorPage />
}

return <Success username={data.userName}/>
```

Or maybe you can use : *useEffect* like suggested in other answers. But I'm not sure that *useEffect* will be executed after the *async* operation. You should try.

Comment: I tried that version too, when I input some weird letters in input field and click enter, it pops up loading screen, and then still same error

Comment: You should put "setIsLoading(false)" even on the "else" condition. EDIT! @callmenikk

Comment: Yes I already had mentioned that one in my code, I can even paste some parts of my code for more understanding, maybe I miss something in code

Comment: Yes I think we miss something else! Can you paste all the Javascript page you are trying to fix? Thanks!

Comment: I fixed bug by my self, in if statement I wrote that `if userStats.data.items.length === []` and bug has fixed, that was about if else statement problem